# Why does rake db:migrate sometimes add trailing whitespace to structure.sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

On some of our developer machines `rake db:migrate` adds trailing whitespace to `structure.sql` which is really annoying because every time a change is made to the database we have to first remove all trailing whitespace from the file.

Anyone know what could be up with that? Where would the whitespace come from? Has it to do with PostgreSQL or is it something else?

Comment: I am also experiencing this and it is SOOOOOO annoying

Comment: Did you find the problem with this?

Comment: Unfortunately we never did find the root of the issue @DickieBoy

Comment: Did you guys also have problems with NOT NULLS appearing and disappearing?

Comment: Yes! All the time and it is so frigging annoying

Comment: I feel so glad I opted for noSQL now 3:D. More seriously, does it affect only a particular config/environment (dev, production) ? What did you mean by "some of our developer machines" ?

Comment: Different postgresql versions? The structure.sql is created using `pg_dump`.

Comment: I've checked that. The versions between developers are either the same or in the same major release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the best day of my life, and maybe yours:

In **PG 11**, this error is not here anymore since `Tablespace` is not written to the dump. So you can upgrade your PG version and get rid of the hook you had for space deletion.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution that you can commit to version control: trim the trailing whitespace as a `db:migrate` hook.

In `lib/tasks/db.rake`:

```
namespace :db do
  def remove_whitespace_in_structure
    if Rails.env.development?
      `sed -i '' -e's/[[:space:]]*$//' db/structure.sql`
    end
  end

  task :migrate do
    remove_whitespace_in_structure
  end
end
```

The above code may look like it's overwriting `db:migrate`, but it's a hook that will run right after the normal `db:migrate` task.

Comment: The advantage of using this solution is that the file is cleaned early.  With the .gitattributes approach if you look at the file system before committing you will see the file with all the extra whitespace.

Comment: Superb answer. Worth noting that I found I also had to write a similar task for `db:test:prepare`, which also seems to generate a `structure.sql`

Answer (score 7):

I just set up a git filter for this. Unfortunately, this is not something you can add to the repo; each team member will have to set it up.

#### In `.gitconfig` (or `.git/config`)

```
[filter "remove-trailing-whitespace"]
  clean = sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
  smudge = cat
```

#### In `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes`

```
db/structure.sql filter=remove-trailing-whitespace
```

See the [documentation on gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for more information on git `filters`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! That could easily be solved by creating a utility script in the bin folder that is run as part of bootstrapping a new developers machine.

Comment: I added the filter attribute in .git/info/attributes instead of .gitattributes and had success as well. Thanks.

Comment: @voxobscuro: I've updated my answer to include `.git/info/attributes`. Thanks :)

Comment: There's a `git` dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, I add the changes that have an actual effect through a `git add -i db/structure.sql` and then `git checkout db/structure.sql` so that the differences in spaces will be omitted.

The alternative we consider in our team is to use another gem for keeping track of the database.

Comment: I wouldn't mind trying data mapper for my next project.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the version differences of your database on each machine.

You can either all have the same version, or in your text editor have it trim trailing spaces on save. 
In sublime add this line to your settings:
`"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true`

Answer (score -2):

I am using this gem in one of my projects and it does the job.

https://github.com/jakeonrails/fix-db-schema-conflicts

When you run `rake db:migrate` it runs a couple of good things; one of them is the `sed` command that removes unnecessary whitespaces.

Comment: This question is about structure.sql, not schema.rb. If you could remove your answer so that the question will receive more attention, that would be appreciated, thanks.